# Mandrill Unsubscribe page/direct link for emails sent outside of Mandrill?

Tags: mandrill

Usually we send out transactional emails through Mandrill, so we rely on their unsubscribe blacklist. I need to send some emails from another service, but still would like the unsubscribe link in the footer to unsubscribe from Mandrill.

Is this possible? MD Merge Tags/Auto Unsubscribe won't cut it of course.

Comment: If you can get the other service to notify you of the unsubscribe (if they have webhooks or similar), you can use Mandrill's [reject (blacklist) API](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/rejects.JSON.html#method=add) to update Mandrill in real-time. Or if you can tolerate a little lag in syncing unsubscribes, you could manually export the list from the other service (daily, or after the campaign ends), and bulk-add it in Mandrill's [reject settings](https://mandrillapp.com/settings/rejections).

Comment: (Or of course, you could build and host your own unsubscribe page that calls Mandrill's API, and point to that in emails sent from the other service.)